# "tfjs_binding.node" not found in @tensorflow installed folder

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, tensorflow, npm

When i try to use some functionalities of tensorflow it later gives and error inshort as  "tfjs_binding.node" not found in @tensorflow insatlled folder.

i have installed python 2.7 as it had to be installed as a requirement before tensor flow ..  and checked its validty by "python -v" as well

so below is when i try to install    @tensorflow/tfjs-node    ..    help me out clear up things plz ...

```
D:\FYP stuff\servermaking\f_I_upoadt2>npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node

> @tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.2.11 install D:\FYP stuff\servermaking\f_I_upoadt2\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
> node scripts/install.js

CPU-windows-1.2.11.zip
* Downloading libtensorflow
[==============================] 310671/bps 100% 0.0s
[==============================] 355964/bps 100% 0.0s
* Building TensorFlow Node.js bindings
node-pre-gyp install failed with error: Error: Command failed: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v3/1.2.11/CPU-windows-1.2.11.zip
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for @tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.2.11 and node@10.15.0 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=D:\\FYP stuff\\servermaking\\f_I_upoadt2\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node\\lib\\napi-v3\\tfjs_binding.node" "--module_name=tfjs_binding" "--module_path=D:\\FYP stuff\\servermaking\\f_I_upoadt2\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node\\lib\\napi-v3" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=3" "--node_napi_label=napi-v3"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\FYP stuff\servermaking\f_I_upoadt2\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=D:\FYP stuff\servermaking\f_I_upoadt2\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v3\tfjs_binding.node --module_name=tfjs_binding --module_path=D:\FYP stuff\servermaking\f_I_upoadt2\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v3 --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\FYP stuff\servermaking\f_I_upoadt2\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\FYP stuff\\servermaking\\f_I_upoadt2\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd D:\FYP stuff\servermaking\f_I_upoadt2\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.13.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm WARN f_i_upoadt2@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN f_i_upoadt2@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ @tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.2.11
updated 1 package and audited 598 packages in 106.757s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

below is the error given after  i try to run the server

```
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\FYP stuff\servermaking\f_I_upoadt2\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v3\tfjs_binding.node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\FYP stuff\servermaking\f_I_upoadt2\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\index.js:44:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I will be glad to have any kind of help or guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First I had to set python v2 as default python when on check version of python.
2. I had to to open Windows Power shell as admin and type in this command shown above.

   ```
   npm install -g windows-build-tools
   ```

   It took several minutes and it was done.
3. Also I installed `@tensorflow/tfjs` and after that `@tensorflow/tfjs-node"` in my project.

That's how I got to solve my issue.

side note =>  some certain node versions on Windows have issues with tensor flow, for example I had to upgrade to  v10.16.3 from v10.15.0.

"Credits for solving issues goes to tensorflow/tfjs team on Github"

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with @tensorflow\tfjs-node version @1.5.2 & @1.7.4 on Windows 10. Node version @12.18.3 LTS

```
Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\E:\hypothesis-manager\facerec\http-service\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v5\tfjs_binding.node
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1187:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\hypothesis-manager\facerec\http-service\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\index.js:58:16)
```

This happens when we try to update and install packages, and some dependencies are not installed properly.
Try to `npm uninstall @tensorflow\tfjs-node` if you are using npm. Then install latest version of tensorflow using `npm i @tensorflow\tfjs-node` it will work. Or try following approach given in comment below if you only want particular version of tensorflow to run in your project (In my case it's @1.5.2).

Comment: I have one possible solution, that works for me on my new machine. There is possibility of `tensorflow.dll` file is not found in napi-v6 or napi-v5 folder in @tensorflow package, that leads to this error even after we reinstall tensorflow/tfjs-node package. So create simple project and install latest version of @tensorflow/tfjs-node. Find Tensorflow.dll file in node_modules at given path for ex. `project\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v6\tensorflow.dll`. Just copy this tensorflow.dll file and pest it in napi-v5 folder of @tensorflow in node_modules in your actual project.

Comment: Or another way is to just copy `tfjs-node` folder form newly created node_modules and paste it in actual project.